# How to parse keys in bash from command line?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to make a command line tool out of a bash script. It is very simple:

```
grep ">" in_file >> out_file.
```

So I want to copy all lines containing '>' from the first file to the second. 
I need a tool that I could run from the command line like this:

```
./tool.sh -input in_file -output out_file
```

-input and -output here are to keys.

I tried the code below:

```
while getopts "i:o:"
do
  case $Option in
          i)       input=$OPTARG;;
          o)     output=$OPTARG;; 
  esac
done

grep -n '>' input >> output
```

But I got an error: tool: input: No such file or directory.

What is wrong here ? And also I want make the 'in' key to be able to take more than one arguments. How can I do this ? I guess I just don't understand correctely how does the getopts work but I didn't find any good description.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I just don't understand correctely how does the getopts work
>   but I didn't find any good description.

In Bash `getopts` is a builtin:

```
$ type -a getopts
getopts is a shell builtin
```

Its behavior is described in `help getopts`:

```
$ help getopts
getopts: getopts optstring name [arg]
    Parse option arguments.

    Getopts is used by shell procedures to parse positional parameters
    as options.
    (...)
    Each time it is invoked, getopts will place the next option in the
    shell variable $name,
```

Your script doesn't work for 2 reasons - you use `getopts` incorrectly
and you do not prepend variable names with `$` to get their
contents. It should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while getopts "i:o:" Option
do
    echo in loop
    case "$Option" in
        i)     input="$OPTARG";;
        o)     output="$OPTARG";; 
    esac
done

echo input: "$input"
echo output: "$output"

grep -n '>' "$input" >> "$output"
```

Comment: The script should also be launched with the correct name of the declared options, in this case ./tool.sh -i in_file -o out_file and not ./tool.sh --input in_file --oputput out_file, since input and output are variables names declared in the script, and not options names (declared in getopts parameter "i:o:")

Comment: Ok, thank you! But what if I want to make it possible to put several files in the input key ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do;

```
#!/bin/bash

grep ">" "$1" >> "out_file."
```

and then call like;

```
./tool.sh in_file
```

`$1` is a positional paramater, meaning the next argument after the script becomes the input file name.
If you wanted to allow the user of the script to specify an outout, use the second positional paramater;

```
#!/bin/bash

grep ">" "$1" >> "$2"
```

and call like;

```
./tool.sh in_file out_file.
```

To add more arguments, simply add more positional paramaters.

Comment: So that means that every time I have to rewrite the script to add as many parameters as I need. But I want to make it automatic.

Comment: ok try this:

`echo "$*" | xargs grep -h ">" >> "out_file."`
This will handle any number of arguments, and won't require editing later.

$* takes all of the arguments you present (ie filenames), which is piped to xargs which turns them into something grep can use.  -h strips the filenames from the output.  If you have spaces in your filenames, use the -0 switch on xargs.  This will also support the use of wildcards as your argument: `./tool.sh file*`